# How do I get navbar to go 100% of page (not viewport) in css flex-box?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the navbar to stretch the height of the page.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 60rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>some nav stuff</nav>
  <section>a tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall
    bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya
    tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall
    bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya
    tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall
    bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya
    tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall
    bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya
    tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall bodya tall body</section>
</main>
```

Comment: remove height:100% and align-items:flex-start .. that's it

Comment: on which element?

Comment: you only have one of each in your code

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: it does for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gzp9q6o3/ unless you definition of "viewport"/"page" is not the one I know

Comment: oh i got it working. why does removing `align-items: flex-start` work?

Comment: check the duplicate. It's the opposite of what you want but still relevant here and explain the effect of align-items